# robotframework - copying resources (keywords, variables, etc) from one project to another

Tags: python, robotframework

Is there any way to copy resources in robot framework from one project to another without actually copying every file, can I just import the project into settings and use the keywords in another project?

In the picture down below, you can see I have two projects called "robotframework-spb" and "robotframework-mch".

On the split screen on the left side is the file "test.robot" used in project "robotframework-spb" and on the right side there is "login.robot" used in different project "robotframework-mch".

What I want to do is to use keywords and files from "robotframework-mch" without actually copying them into the project, is this possible in robot framework? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: you can create resource files with settings an dkeywords and import it in every project you need

Comment: it seems you are already using a separate file for the keywords. as Psytho said, you can any keyword file as a resourse in the settings of the project. If you want to maintain project file independency then you should probably create a third "master" folder where you would store all the common files for all projects and then import those in every project where you wanted to use them

Comment: And isn't there a way to share a test case from one project to another? Let's say I will do what I need in one project and then use the test case in another?

Comment: You can use the same approach but you cannot import tests from another file. What you can do is execute multiple robot scripts and reach the same result